# The import com.liferay.util.bridges cannot be resolved

Tags: java, liferay

I'm using Eclipse IDE and I have the following line in my code:

```
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;
```

But there is a red underline on this line and when hover on it it shows me this error:

> The import com.liferay.util.bridges cannot be resolved.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add [`util-bridges-6.1.0`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/util-bridges/6.1.0/util-bridges-6.1.0.jar) to your CLASSPATH. [Choose version](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/util-bridges/) that is compatible with your project.

Answer (score 0):

after seven years from this post I hit the same problem, raised suddenly without any modification in my IDE and/or project (yesterday I switched off my PC without problem and this morning the error came up). 
As suggested by Tomasz I checked my liferay-plugin-package configuration and I discovered that the util-bridges jar was already there but strangely removing that jar from Portal Dependency list solved the problem.
So, at the end, we have two opposite solutions for the very same problem(!)
Really weird!